# VSTO: Open another MailItem in same Inspector window

Tags: c#, .net, vsto, outlook-addin, outlook-2010

Does outlook allow to open another MailItem in same Inspector window? Like outlook native functionality of "Privious/Next" buttons in Inspector window:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/4K1Ya.jpg